# How to write a custom pickler for a case class with a List member?

Tags: scala, scala-pickling

I am trying to write a custom pickler for a case class which has a List[String] member. I am currently using scala-pickling version 0.10.1

I am aware about the `builder.beginCollection` method to pickle collections, but I was not able to get any documentation about its use to unpickle. After much reading of the scala-pickler source code [I have found some indication](https://github.com/scala/pickling/blob/0.10.x/core/src/main/scala/scala/pickling/PBuilderReader.scala#L19) on how to use it properly.

Right now I have the following code, which generates, I think the wrong output (about that after the example). I would appreciate either a piece of example code or a link to some documentation.

```
import scala.pickling._, json._, Defaults._

case class Beta(isSecond : Boolean, notSecond : List[String])

object BetaPickler extends Pickler[Beta] {
    override val tag = FastTypeTag[Beta]

    override def pickle(picklee: Beta, builder: PBuilder): Unit = {
        builder.hintTag(tag) // This is always required
        builder.pinHints()
        builder.beginEntry(picklee)

        builder.putField("isSecond", {
            b => b.hintTag(FastTypeTag.Boolean).beginEntry(picklee.isSecond).endEntry()
        })

        builder.putField("notSecond", { b => {
            b.hintTag(FastTypeTag[String])

            b.beginEntry()
            b.beginCollection(picklee.notSecond.size)

            picklee.notSecond.foreach((item: String) => {

                b.putElement(pb => {
                    pb.hintTag(implicitly[FastTypeTag[String]])
                    stringPickler.pickle(item, pb)
                })
            })

            builder.endCollection()
            builder.endEntry()
        }
        })

        builder.unpinHints()
        builder.endEntry()
    }
}

implicit def pickler: scala.pickling.Pickler[Beta] = BetaPickler

val xBeta : Beta = Beta(true, List("one","three","four"))
```

So, this is the example code, you can copy :paste it into the REPL, it should work. The problem is in the output JSON, where the `notSecond` member of the class `Beta` is not rendered properly.
As you can see the notSecond object has an empty "value" member, and the actual "elem" array is outside, immediately after the "notSecond" object, while I would expect it to be inside, in place of that "value" member.

```
scala> xBeta.pickle
res0: scala.pickling.json.pickleFormat.PickleType =
JSONPickle({
    "$type": "Beta",
    "isSecond": {
        "$type": "scala.Boolean",
        "value": true
    },
    "notSecond": {
        "$type": "java.lang.String",
        "value": "()"
    },
        "elems": [
            {
            "$type": "java.lang.String",
            "value": "one"
        },
            {
            "$type": "java.lang.String",
            "value": "three"
        },
            {
            "$type": "java.lang.String",
            "value": "four"
        }
        ]
})
```

I would appreciate some comments on the way I am pickling the List collection, and maybe a fix for my example.
Thanks a lot!